# Butterfly Backup server

Tags: backup, bash, network-attached-storage, backup-restoration, incremental-backup

I have a [Butterfly Backup](https://matteoguadrini.github.io/Butterfly-Backup/) server. I implemented a solution as described in this article: [dev.to](https://dev.to/matteoguadrini/implement-an-open-source-backup-restore-system-4cpo).
In my sever list, I have two NAS, used as user file repositories; the files change and are changed every minute.
For this reason, I have chosen to implement my backup server with an incremental engine. This is the command that starts at night:

```
bb backup -L /mnt/srv_user/srv.list -d /backup/srv_user -C /nas -t Unix -u unas -r 15 -e
```

I also followed the documentation ([docs](https://butterfly-backup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to produce the above command, and everything seemed to be functional and properly configured.
But I realized that some subfolders of the nas under backup, are transferred even if there are no changes, instead, it should create a hard link to the existing file.

This problem does not do it on all folders but only on some.

Answer (score 1):

Butterfly Backup is nothing more than an rsync wrapper. Use the `--link-dest` flag to create hard links on files. Most likely, the file system where you are placing your catalog does not support hard links. I have a Butterfly Backup server with its catalog in an ext4 file system, and I have no problem.